# worksheet change event only works when region selected - how to adjust to automatic update

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

the combination of this sub in a module

```
Sub hithere3()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Unique As Boolean

For Each Rng In Worksheets("Sheet8").Range("FS3:FS30") 'for each cell     in     your B1 to B30 range, sheet1
Unique = True 'we'll assume it's unique
Lastunique = Worksheets("TRADES").Range("C:C").Find("*",     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
For i = 3 To Lastunique 'for each cell in the unique ID cache
    If Rng.Value = Worksheets("TRADES").Cells(i, 3).Value Then 'we       check    if it is equal
        Unique = False 'if yes, it is not unique
    End If
Next
If Unique Then Worksheets("TRADES").Cells(Lastunique + 1, 3) = Rng 'adds    if it is unique
Next
End Sub
```

with the loop check in a worksheet change events

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("FS3:FS33")) Is Nothing Then
'Do nothing '
Else
Call hithere3
End If
End Sub
```

works except it only updates when I select one of the cells in FS3:FS33

Can anyone suggest how this can be overcome?

maybe with a workchange change range selection type from below?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Rng As Range, Dn As Range, n As Long
Dim RngB As Range, RngC As Range
If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Count = 1 And Target.Row > 1 Then
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
Set RngB = Range(Range("B2"), Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set RngC = Range(Range("C2"), Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
ray = Array(RngB, RngC)
For n = 0 To 1
    For Each Dn In ray(n)
        If Not Dn.Address(0, 0) = "C1" And Not Dn.Value = "" Then
            .Item(Dn.Value) = Empty
        End If
    Next Dn
Next n
Range("C2").Resize(.Count) = Application.Transpose(.Keys)
End With
End If
```

Comment: What is the number and description of this error?

Comment: debug error 6 - it just refers to that line - something like ..runtime error

Comment: I restarted workbook and now there is no error

Comment: another day same problem - it won't update

Comment: We will need a fresh start on this I think. Either add current codes under your OP, or create a new fresh question. This is very difficult to read. Please write in logical order, what code if run first, then second etc. and what error exactly are you getting and on which line. Thank you. We will overcome this, don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

Use either the worksheet *Calculate* event or the worksheet *Change* event:

1. use *Calculate* if the range contains **formulas**
2. use *Change* if the cells in the range are changed **manually**

Comment: changing `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)` to `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionCalculate(ByVal Target As Range)` doesn't do anything

Comment: I get the error procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having same name when I change `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(` to `Worksheet_Calculate(`

Comment: the range does contain formulas but ...ammending this still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

`If Intersect(Target, Range("FS3:FS33")) Is Nothing` is the culprit. You must change `Range("FS3:FS33")` to whatever range you want to affect this change.

Comment: `Range("FS3:FS33")` I want to be referenced everytime there is a change there then execute `sub hithere3()`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but I am close to giving up on this

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out, the following code works :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_calculate()
If Range("FS3:FS33") Is Nothing Then
'Do nothing'
Else
Call hithere3
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The code is driving me crazy the previious one and possibly this one. The one I am using now works ok for four lines of code and the I get  ############ and debug of the` hithere3`

Comment: ah - yes your code does work. Its good you posted this because I thought  had it - then you found it for me , so , thanks for this. Hopefully no more problems :D

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) '<<delete the "Selection" from the name of event
If Intersect(Target, Range("FS3:FS33")) Is Nothing Then
'Do nothing '
Else
Call hithere3
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: His point is that you should be using the `Worksheet_Change` event instead of the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event

Comment: Posted few seconds after your answer. But since you ask, there is a difference between `Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)` - only triggers when you click somewhere and `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` - triggers when you change a cell value for example. But you have found the `Worksheet_calculate()` and if it works, then this is obsolete. I thought you had manual input cells in the range `Range("FS3:FS33")`, but I guess you have formulas in there. In that case `Worksheet_calculate()` is OK.